# Add border to radioButton with text on isChecked

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want to add border to radiobutton with text on isChecked

I tried Style.Trigger but it didn't seem to have action
Also tried via ControlTemplate.Trigger but referencing to both grid and text box says Parameter is not recognized

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}"
       TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}"
       x:Key="MenuButtonTheme">

    <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
                    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                x:Name="GridMain">
                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Property=Content}"
                                   x:Name="ButtonText"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                Margin="20,0,0,0">

                        </TextBlock>
                    </Grid>

                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="ButtonText" Property="Margin" Value="30,0,0,0"></Setter>
                            <!-- <Setter TargetName="ButtonText" Property="BorderThickness" Value="5"></Setter> -->
                            <!-- <Setter TargetName="GridMain" Property="BorderThickness" Value="5"></Setter> -->
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="GridMain" Property="Background" Value="#424549"></Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>

        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"></Setter>
    </Style.Setters>

    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="5"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#7289da"></Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
    
</Style>
```

Comment: when you need border, use Border element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TextBlock doesn't have a border, so it's impossible to set a value for the border either.
It can be solved in two ways.

1. Use instead of TextBlock element TextBox in read-only mode.

   ```
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
                <Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            x:Name="GridMain">
                    <TextBox Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                             x:Name="ButtonText"
                             VerticalAlignment="Center"
                             Margin="20,0,0,0"
                             IsReadOnly="True"/>
                </Grid>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="ButtonText" Property="Margin" Value="30,0,0,0"></Setter>
                        <Setter TargetName="ButtonText" Property="BorderThickness" Value="5"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="GridMain" Property="Background" Value="#424549"></Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
   ```
2. Since you have only one element in the panel, you can use Border instead.

   ```
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
                <Border VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        x:Name="GridMain">
                    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Property=Content}"
                               x:Name="ButtonText"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            Margin="20,0,0,0">

                    </TextBlock>
                </Border>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="ButtonText" Property="Margin" Value="30,0,0,0"></Setter>
                        <Setter TargetName="GridMain" Property="BorderThickness" Value="5"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="GridMain" Property="Background" Value="#424549"></Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
   ```